# Pick another RDBMS

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, postgresql, rdbms

Other then Oracle, MySQL, and PostgreSQL, what is out there? Is there anything else used in a production environment? By production I mean it's used to support an active project or application and not an unstable system. I'm curious about other database systems (aside from NoSQL) that are applicable for use.

Looking at the feature set of those three, just about everything is covered. Why should I use something other then MySQL?

Bonus points if it works with Ibatis, some sort of Java connector is necessary though.

Comment: I've worked with SQL Server in a serious, heavy-load production environment (a commercial web app at a major bank), and while I'm the last person to praise a Microsoft product I found it pretty damn solid, and very fast. And the application was 100% Java with an *excellent* 3rd-party JDBC driver.

Comment: We use SQL Server and we are a hardcore Java shop. And I'm also the last person to give any free promotions for Microsoft. But they do have some good stuff.

Comment: "Looking at the feature set of those three, just about everything is covered. Why should I use something other then MySQL?" Note that the feature set of the other 2 is **not** the same as MySQL - two areas of functionality that occur to me are analytical (windowing) functions and recursive CTEs, which are supported in a number of RDBMSs (including Oracle) but not MySQL,as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't mention:

- <strike>SQL Server</strike>
- Teradata
- Pervasive
- Firebird
- Informix
- Sybase

Comment: Drop SQL Server. Can you explain the other choices, how they differ with the ones I provided, and advantages / disadvantages? What keeps them out of the spotlight (at least in my opinion)?

Comment: @Josh K, don't ask a vague question and then criticize a response that perfectly answers you question.

Comment: @Josh K: Pervasive is has had more of an embedded focus (used for AutoCAD in the past, along with various accounting packages).  MySQL being free and the darling of OS is the main reason alternatives get noticed -- proof of that lies in the Express editions (Oracle, SQL Server, DB2) to combat it.

Comment: @mikerobi: The question isn't vague, and it wasn't a criticism. I am not, and will not be, using SQL Server so it's not applicable. I did ask for (and received) an explanation on how they differ from stock MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

- SQLite
- DB2
- Informix
- [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)
- HSQLDB
- Ingres

Comment: @Josh K, I added a link to Derby, but I'm not going to bother with a bunch of products whose home pages will be the number 1 result if you google them.

Comment: I noticed, Derby was the only one I had trouble with.

Comment: Derby. Lightweight and perfect coupled with Java apps.

Comment: I'd prefer H2 over Derby. It seems to have a lot more momentum currently. If the aim is a Java embedded DB, the HSQLDB is worth looking at as well. 2.0 was recently released and has an impressive feature set.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Oracle's Berkeley DB. In same memory space as app: key-value pair, transactions, isolation, very fast and performant. C, Java nd XML versions. 
Also, this might be useful: http://blogs.oracle.com/natarajan/resource/Databases_for_Cloud.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If MySQL does the job for you, I don't think you need to change. But don't forget that MySQL is **not** free. If you are building a commercial application on top of MySQL, you have to buy a license.

Featurewise I think PostgreSQL is superior to MySQL (better query optimizer, windowing functions, common table expressions, check constraints, deferrable constraint just to name a few that MySQL is lacking) and it is *really* free.

MySQL might have a slight advantage if you need multi-master replication but there are solutions for PostgreSQL as well. And I guess we'll be seeing more now that streaming replication is built into Postgres (since 9.0)

To complete the list of databases there is also Greenplum (data warehouse, similar to Teradata)